# Segmentation fault in sscanf while reading FILE

Tags: c, string, scanf

When I compile my program I get no error, but when I start it I get a "Segmentation fault". The FILE I try to read is build like this:

```
322;Peter;m
233;Chad;m
211;Lisa;w
```

I have the strong feeling my sscanf function is the issue.
Please help me.

```
#define MAXCHAR 30
#define MAXZEILE 40
void speicher(char Z[MAXCHAR]){

FILE *QUELL;
int a;
char n[MAXCHAR];
char g;
char string[MAXZEILE];
    QUELL=fopen(Z,"r");
    fgets(string, MAXZEILE, QUELL);
    sscanf(string, "%d;%s;%c", &a, n, &g);
    printf("%d, %s, %c", a, n, g);
    fclose(QUELL);
}
```

Comment: You don't check whether `fopen` succeeded. Also, post a [mcve] if you can.

Comment: It can not be more minimal than this. I aleady shortened it. Thanks for your input

Comment: We like to see "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable". What you have is minimal but it is neither complete nor verifiable.

Comment: use `%29s` in `sscanf` to avoid buffer overflow

Answer (score 1):

My bad:
the MAXCHAR for the FILE input was to low.
The FILE had more than 30 chars.

Answer (score 0):

In your sscanf `%s` does not know when to stop:

```
sscanf(string, "%d;%s;%c", &a, n, &g);
```

Without properly tokenizing on `;`, `%s` will keep grabbing input until the next whitespace (which in your case will be the end of the line). It should be changed to

```
sscanf(string, "%d;%[^;];%c", &a, n, &g);
```

The `%[^;]` specifies to grab characters that are not a `;` thus achieving the desired result.

For more robustness, you may want to look into using `strtok` to first separate it `;` and then process each individual segment.

Comment: *keep grabbing input until the end of the line* - I think it stops on white  space

Answer (score 0):

I assume that to your purposes the lines written below are enough

```
ReturnVal = sscanf(strinp1, "%d %c %100[^;] %c %c", &a, &Separator1, 
                   n,&Separator2, &g);
```

1. Read an integer
2. Read then the character ';'
3. Read at most 100 characters, stop reading encountering the character ';'
4. Read then again the character ;
5. Read the next character. (man or woman???).